# Cases and Switch Issue

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that simulates an ATM. So it tracks account balances, withdrawals and deposits in a very basic matter.

Everything works well during the first iteration, but if I go to make two or more deposits or withdrawals, the account balances default back to the original amount.

Here is an example of what is currently happening: I have $1,000 in my account initially. I make a deposit of $50. It prints out that I now have $1,050 in my account and asks if I would like to perform any other actions. (This is all good). If I select that I want to make another deposit of $100, it says my new account balance is $1,100 instead of $1,150. It does not store my latest account balance when I perform new withdrawals or deposits.

The second (less important) issue is that each time a withdrawal is made, there is a $2.50 fee for each withdrawal that also gets subtracted from my account balance.

I have not learned loops yet, only Cases, If statements and If Else Statements.

Is it possible to do what I want to do? Below is my code. Thank you in advance! This is my first time posting, so if I have pasted my code wrong, I apologize.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
using namespace std; // opens library for "cout"

int main()
{
    float test;
    int logout;
    string name;
    float balance;
    float fee;
    int choice;
    float withdraw;
    float deposit;
    float bonus;
    bonus = 2.50;
    balance = 1572.36;
    fee = 12.50;
    char answer;

    cout << "Hello, thank you for banking with Pallet Town Bank.\n";

    cout << "Please enter your name. ";

    cin >> name;

    cout << "Hello " << name << ". Your current balance is $" << balance << ".\n";
    cout << "There will be a a service fee of $12.50 subtracted from your "
            "account.\n";
    cout << "Your updated balance will be $" << balance - fee << " \n";
    cout << "What would you like to do today?\n";
    do
    {
        cout << "\n1 - Current Balance\n2 - Withdraw\n3 - deposit\n4 - Log "
                "Out\nOption: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) 
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "\nCurrent Balance is " << balance - fee - withdraw + deposit
                 << " \n";
            cout << "Would you like to take any other actions today?\n";

            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "\nWithdraw - How much would you like to withdraw? $";
            cin >> withdraw;
            cout << "Your new balance after withdrawing $" << withdraw << " will be $"
                 << balance - fee - withdraw + deposit << "\n";
            cout << "Would you like to take any other actions today?\n";

            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "\nDeposit - How much would you like to deposit? $";
            cin >> deposit;

            test = balance - fee - withdraw + deposit;
            cout << "Your new balance after depositing $" << deposit << " will be $"
                 << test << endl; //<<balance - fee - withdraw + deposit<<"\n";
            cout << "Would you like to take any other actions today? Y or N \n";
            cin >> answer;

            cout << answer;
            if (answer == 'y' || 'Y')
            {
                test = balance - fee - withdraw + deposit + deposit;
                cout << "Your new balance after depositing $" << deposit << " will be $"
                     << test << endl;
            }
            // cout <<"Your new balance after depositing $"<<deposit<<" will be $"
            // <<test<< endl; //<<balance - fee - withdraw + deposit<<"\n";
            // cout <<"Would you like to take any other actions today?\n";

            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "\nLog Out - Thank you for banking with Pallet Town Bank. Have "
                    "a great day!";
        }
    } while (choice != 4);
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Compilers won't care, but humans reading it will. You may find it clear now, but in a week you'll likely think otherwise.

Comment: "`if (answer == 'y'|| 'Y')`" -- this does not do what you think it does. This is your problem.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Just to add the correct test: if ((answer == 'y')|| (answer == 'Y'))

Comment: `float` for a balance? That's only good for 7 significant figures. Work in cents instead.

Comment: you never update `balance` with the new value?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Thanks for the updated code. Unfortunately that does not fix the issue with not updating the new amount

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks! I thought this would be the problem, so can I just say balance = balance - fee - withdraw + deposit ?

Comment: yes that will probably work

Comment: @AlanBirtles unfortunately that creates the same issue. Thanks though!

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: You can also use `if (toupper(answer) == 'Y')`.  Using `toupper` or `tolower` before comparing will reduce the amount of compares.

Comment: BTW, `using std::cout;` *opens up namespace for cout*.  Your `using namespace std` allows for all of the `std` symbols, not just `cout` or `cin`.

Comment: Re: `using namespace std; // opens library for "cout"`" -- that comment shows a fundamental misunderstanding. That using declaration tells the compiler to pretend that every name defined in the namespace `std` is also defined in the global namespace. If you don't have that using declaration you can (and should) use the fully qualified name, `std::cout`.

Comment: Prefer to use [fixed point notation](https://www.google.com/search?q=fixed+point+notation+c%2B%2B&oq=fixed+point+notation+c%2B%2B&aqs=chrome..69i57.11408j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) when dealing with finances.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue, as Alan Birtles points out, is that you never update the `balance` value; you just store the temporary calculations in the `test` variable.

Here's how you could change your code. I tried interpreting the expected behaviour of the program as best I could from the text:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    const double fee = 12.50;
    double balance = 1572.36;

    cout << "Hello, thank you for banking with Pallet Town Bank.\n";

    cout << "Please enter your name. ";

    string name;
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Hello " << name << ". Your current balance is $" << balance << ".\n";
    cout << "There will be a a service fee of $12.50 subtracted from your "
            "account.\n";
    cout << "Your updated balance will be $" << (balance -= fee) << " \n";
    cout << "What would you like to do today?\n\n";

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "1 - Current Balance" << '\n'
             << "2 - Withdraw" << '\n'
             << "3 - deposit" << '\n'
             << "4 - Log Out" << '\n'
             << "Option: ";
        int choice;
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;
        if (choice == 4) break;

        switch (choice) 
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Current Balance is " << balance << '\n';
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Withdraw - How much would you like to withdraw? $";
            double withdraw;
            cin >> withdraw;
            cout << "Your new balance after withdrawing $" << withdraw << " will be $"
                 << (balance -= withdraw) << '\n';
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "Deposit - How much would you like to deposit? $";
            double deposit;
            cin >> deposit;
            cout << "Your new balance after depositing $" << deposit << " will be $"
                 << (balance += deposit) << '\n';
            break;            
        }

        cout << "Would you like to take any other actions today? ";
        char answer;
        cin >> answer;
        cout << endl;
        if (toupper(answer) == 'N') break;
    }

    cout << "Log Out - Thank you for banking with Pallet Town Bank. Have a great day!" << endl;
}
```

[Live demo](http://cpp.sh/72sep)

**Changes**

- First of all, every time a modification is made (withdrawal/deposit), we need to actually update the `balance`. We can do so by using the `+=` or `-=` operators (called "compound assignment" operators): when writing `balance += x`, we're adding `x` to `balance`, and when writing `balance -= x` we're subtracting. These expressions are equivalent to `balance = balance + x` and `balance = balance - x`, respectively.
- I moved the `"Would you like to [...]"` part outside the `switch` statement, to avoid repeating it in each case.
- As pointed out in the comments, `answer == 'Y' || 'y'` isn't the same as `answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y'`. I changed that to `toupper(answer) == 'Y'`.
- I moved the logout handling outside the `while` loop, so that whenever the loop terminates, the logout message is always shown. That allows us to remove `case 4` from the `switch` statement, by checking at the beginning if `choice == 4` and then `break`ing out of the loop accordingly. This also implies the loop becomes a `while (true)` loop. Probably there is a more elegant way.

### Even better

If you're confortable with functions, I would suggest refactoring the code, isolating each operation individually:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


const int FEE = 1250; // fee in cents


//---- Utilities ----//

string moneyString(int cents) {
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << cents/100 << '.' << cents % 100;
    return oss.str();
}

int toCents(double money) {
    return int(round(money*100));
}

int getMoney() {
    double money;
    cin >> money;
    return toCents(money);
}


//---- User input ----//

// Available choices
enum Choices {
    BALANCE = 1,
    WITHDRAW = 2,
    DEPOSIT = 3,
    LOGOUT = 4
};

short int getChoice() {
    short int choice = 0;

    while (choice < 1 or choice > 4) {
        cout << "1 - Current Balance" << '\n'
             << "2 - Withdraw" << '\n'
             << "3 - deposit" << '\n'
             << "4 - Log Out" << '\n'
             << "Option: ";

        string input;
        cin >> input;
        choice = atoi(input.c_str());

        cout << endl;
    }

    return choice;
}

bool userWantsMoreActions() {
    cout << "Would you like to take any other actions today? ";
    char answer;
    cin >> answer;
    cout << endl;
    return toupper(answer) == 'Y';
}


//---- Actions ----//

void greeting(double &balance) {
    cout << "Hello, thank you for banking with Pallet Town Bank.\n";

    cout << "Please enter your name. ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Hello " << name << ". Your current balance is $" << moneyString(balance) << ".\n";
    cout << "There will be a a service fee of $12.50 subtracted from your account.\n";
    cout << "Your updated balance will be $" << moneyString(balance -= FEE) << " \n";
    cout << "What would you like to do today?\n\n";
}

void printBalance(const double &balance) {
    cout << "Current Balance is " << balance << '\n';
}

void withdraw(double &balance) {
    cout << "Withdraw - How much would you like to withdraw? $";
    int withdraw = getMoney();
    cout << "Your new balance after withdrawing $" << withdraw << " will be $"
         << (balance -= withdraw -= FEE) << '\n';
}

void deposit(double &balance) {
    cout << "Deposit - How much would you like to deposit? $";
    int deposit = getMoney();
    cout << "Your new balance after depositing $" << moneyString(deposit) 
         << " will be $" << moneyString(balance += deposit -= FEE) << '\n';
}



int main()
{
    // Initialize a sample session:
    double balance = 157236;

    greeting(balance);
    while (true)
    {
        short int choice = getChoice();

        if      (choice == Choices::BALANCE) printBalance(balance);
        else if (choice == Choices::WITHDRAW) withdraw(balance);
        else if (choice == Choices::DEPOSIT) deposit(balance);
        else if (choice == Choices::LOGOUT) break;

        if (not userWantsMoreActions()) break;
    }

    cout << "Log Out - Thank you for banking with Pallet Town Bank. Have a great day!" << endl;
}
```

[Live demo](http://cpp.sh/5pf3r)

Comment: Thanks for the help! One weird thing is happening now. Let's say I make a deposit of $100 and my new balance is $500. If I say that I would like to make another deposit, before I enter my new deposit amount, it automatically re-adds my last deposit amount to my current balance. See the print out below..

Deposit - How much would you like to deposit? $100
Your new balance after depositing $100 will be $659.86
Would you like to take any other actions today? Y or N 
y
yYour new balance after depositing $100 will be $759.86

1 - Current Balance
2 - Withdraw
3 - deposit
4 - Log Out

Comment: @LBrunot That is because (in your code), in `case 3`, you repeat the `balance + deposit - fee` calculation: first you do it once, and then, when checking if `answer == 'Y'` you repeat it. In the version I posted above I fixed that, and it works fine.

Comment: I really appreciate the help on that last edit but I haven't learned any of that. Im going to have to keep trying to edit the first one you sent to get it to do what I want. Thanks

Comment: @LBrunot No problem, but I meant the first one. Isn't that one working for you? Try it [here](http://cpp.sh/8ail2v) (edited the link)

Comment: Unfortunately not. It keeps adding my initial deposit and won't update if I add a new deposit. See here:  Deposit - How much would you like to deposit? $100
Your new balance after depositing $100 will be $1659.86
Would you like to take any other actions today? Y or N 
y
Your new balance after depositing $100 will be $1759.86. 

As soon as I choose to complete another action, it just adds my original deposit

Comment: @LBrunot Ah, I see! Sorry about that. I'm fixing it.

Comment: So it works when I run it in the link you sent me, but when I paste it into CodeBlocks, it does not work...What am I missing?

Comment: @LBrunot I've edited it, I believe it should be fixed now. The new link is [here](http://cpp.sh/72sep). If it doesn't work on your end, is it a compiler error or is it the actual behaviour?

Comment: I believe that worked! Thanks for all the help. One more hopefully easy question. Im not concerned with elegance, but I haven't learned about While(True) or toupper. Is there a way that I can make this closer to what I originally wrote with "do" and with if(answer=='y')?

Comment: The reason I ask is that I'm required to have those four cases, and I've been trying to the last couple hours and can't get it to compile when I move the case 4 back in.

Comment: @LBrunot [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) is just a utility that converts any character to uppercase (so you don't have to compare each case separately). You can replace it with `answer == 'y' or answer == 'Y'`. It seems you already solved it, but if you want to keep `case 4`, you can use a [`goto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto) to break out of the `switch` and the `while` loop simultaneously